# How can I update my perforce have list to reflect my empty workspace on a new PC?

Tags: perforce

Recently our development team received new pc's. In an effort to make this transition smoother, I would like to be able to explain to my co-workers how to continue using the client they already have set up to pull files to and from the new pc while eventually ignoring the old pc workspace altogether.

I know about adjusting the attributes of the client itself and allowing the client to be accessed by different hosts. What I'm looking to do now is update the perforce have list for the given client to reflect the files (or lack thereof) that are on the new pc's file system (in the correctly mapped location, obviously).

I'm not sure if it is possible with the p4 flush command for perforce to know which revision of an existing workspace file i have without explicitly telling perforce which revision it is...? (this seems like its asking a lot)

Apart from files that Do exist in the workspace, is there a command that will update the have list to #0 for files that don't exist in the workspace?

OR

Is the sledgehammer approach:

submit any pending changes in the old and/or new workspace
remove any files that may have already been forced into the (new) workspace 
$:p4 flush [workspace root]/...#0

appropriate in this situation?

Comment: Mark & Mike both have very helpful answers. The issue I had with Mike's answer is I would have to keep forcing the get revision on the latest to get perforce to ignore the have list and actually copy the file(s), because I didn't want to copy the entire workspace tree (too big).

I decided to revert or submit changes, delete the contents of the workspace directory on the new machine and run the following command `p4 flush //depot/...#0`

This may not always be the best, and in reality it is the same as `p4 sync //depot/...#0`, because syncing to rev0 would have done the local deletion for me.

Comment: Given the new workspace is empty and the perforce have list is incorrect,

When the command `p4 flush //depot/...#0` is run,

Then the have list will reflect the new, empty workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the existing workspaces is an option, then this should be pretty easy. It sounds like you already know how to make a workspace accessible from a different host (you can leave it blank to make it accessible by any host). If you copy the workspace folder to the new PC, and update the root of the workspace as necessary, it should "just work" without any additional changes.

Comment: Mike, thank you also for your reply. This was my first thought after reading the documentation I mentioned to Mark. I wanted to try and avoid this simply because of the volume of files we keep in any given workspace at any given time (10s of thousands). Most of the reasoning behind these volumes is dependency catching, but...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe that using a workspace name as your revision modifier will do what you want.  For example `p4 flush //depot/path/some/file@workspacename`.  For new machines, we often go through these basic steps to avoid having to resync files.

1. Copy the files in the workspace from machine 1 to machine 2
2. Create a client that matches the old client's mappings
3. In the new client, run:
   `p4 flush //depot/...@oldclientname`

Comment: Mark, thanks for your prompt reply. I saw this in the p4 documentation for the flush command, but didn't want to write a document explaining (again) how to create new Perforce clients.